# Saving properties in iOS

Tags: ios, properties, nsuserdefaults

I am building my first big iOS App and I am using a lot of view controllers and a tab bar.
I want some properties (like `username`, `isUSerLoggedIn` etc) to be accessed from every view controller. I am using the `NSUserDefaults` to save these properties. Is this a good technique?

Comment: Yes, NSUserDefaults is perfect for that to begin with.

Comment: yes. it is correct way.

Comment: Do you require those properties to be persisted even after application quits?

Comment: No but I will check if the user is logged in each time the app launches so I can update the properties like isUserLogin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways:

1) You could use KeyChain.

Example:

```
//Initializing
KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"YourAppLogin" accessGroup:nil];
//Saving
[keychainItem setObject:@"password you are saving" forKey:kSecValueData];
[keychainItem setObject:@"username you are saving" forKey:kSecAttrAccount];
//Getting
NSString *password = [keychainItem objectForKey:kSecValueData];
NSString *username = [keychainItem objectForKey:kSecAttrAccount];
//deleting
[keychainItem resetKeychainItem];
```

2) Or you could use NSUserDefaults

Example:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *pword = [prefs setObject:@"yourpassword" ForKey:@"password"];
NSString *username = [prefs setObject:@"username" ForKey:@"username"];
[prefs synchronize];
//getting 
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *pword = [prefs objectForKey:@"password"];
NSString *username = [prefs objectForKey:@"username"];
```

Method 1 is more secure than Method 2 because NSUserDefaults are just a plist. Somebody steals your device, does a back up and has all the passwords in a nice xml file. With Encryption, method 2 becomes method 1, only more complicated.

Comment: [prefs synchronize]; what is doing?

Comment: [prefs synchronize]; saves the data...

Comment: I am using NSUserDefaults withou sync and is working fine. Anyway thank you for your great answer

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefault is meant for persistent saving.

username is a good example, isUSerLoggedIn not always (think that it will be saved even if your application has been terminate, is that what you want?).

In some of the cases you should consider using singletons::

```
static SingletonSample *sharedObject;
+ (SingletonSample*)sharedInstance
    {
         if (sharedObject == nil) {
         sharedObject = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
          }
    return sharedObject;
    }
```

Comment: I disagree with using Singletons for this. It's just an excuse for not partitioning state within the application properly. It's not different from storing state in the app delegate. Also - `alloctWithZone:`? That isn't really needed nowadays. The modern method is to call the class's `init` in a `dispatch_once()` block.